# Cannot commit -No transaction is active in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Android project,am facing a problem in sqlite database.The problem is **Cannot commit No transaction is active in sqlite** how to clear this error and get rid of it.What is the cause of this error and why this error is occuring and one thing when I tried to update my table with more than 5-8 set of data means the app crashed and in the logcat this message is coming.And the error screenshot i have attached which was the output of the **logcat**.

[image: This is the error when i try to update my table]

Comment: Would you post your code too?

Comment: Maybe you have called `commit()` without calling `beginTransaction()`.

Comment: which code @Benedictus

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not doing transactions, and doing too much work on your main thread.
Try executing it using transactions and InsertHelpers:

```
    database.beginTransaction();
    DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper ih = new DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper(database,TABLE_NAME);
    final int column = ih.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
            ih.prepareForInsert();
            ih.bind(column, columnData);
            ih.execute();
            ih.close();
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            database.endTransaction();}
```